# leaving Anaconda environment in Terminal (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I recently installed Anaconda on my Mac for starting to code with Python using Spyder, but decided to switch to VSCode (without starting Anaconda) which I find less confusing (I'm a casual coder). However, every time I open Terminal now on my Mac, the prompt starts with "(base)" which seems to indicate I'm still in the Anaconda Base environment. How do I switch back to the default option? I understand that I can exit the environment with "conda deactivate", but when I open another Terminal I'm back in (base).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the "default option"? Normally it's "base".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use anaconda, just remove it.

Anaconda goes into the base environment at startup. You can leave it with
`conda deactivate`.

You can also deactivate this startup function with

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I don't want to remove Anaconda yet as I might want to go back to it later.